# how to make my site look like in following image on search engines result

Tags: web, seo, search-engine, meta-tags

I was wondering if is it possible to make same thing by myself, or Search Engines does that by themselves?

I want to add some links like here: [image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Google does this on it's own and all you can do is to (then) remove some of the links through the Google Webmaster Tools.

They are commonly named [Site Links](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=47334) and you can google for "How to get Site Links Google SERP" and so forth - there are thousands of tips for helping Google along.

A clear navigational structure and internal link structure help of course, and consistent anchor texts.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, Google automagically pics those up - there is no direct way to set them. 
Make sure you have a proper site map, and then wait I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, google will generate that links for you.